# HTML5 drag and drop events - dragLeave fires before drop

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, dom-events

In drag and drop the dragLeave event sometimes fires before the drop event.

This is causing problems because the target is getting the listeners in dragEnter with dragLeave and drop removing the listeners.  If dragLeave fires before drop, then there is no listener for the drop.

I *think* the reason has something to do with another contra-intuitive: the dragEnter sometimes fires multiple times for the same target, even with propagation off.  With multiple dragEnters, one would spawn a drop while the others would spawn a dragLeave.  If this is the case, perhaps I could associate the dragLeave with the dragEnter - but I see no means of that coordination.

```
function dragEnter( e ) {

  e.stopPropatation();

  // is multiple fires of dragEnter for same cell
  if( curCell == this ) return;

  curCell = this;
  curCell.addEventListener( 'drop', drop, true );
  curCell.addEventListener( 'dragover', dragOver, true );
  curCell.addEventListener( 'dragleave', dragLeave, true );

  ...
}

function dragLeave( e ) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  curCell.removeEventListener( 'drop', drop, true );
  curCell.removeEventListener( 'dragover', dragOver, true );
  curCell.removeEventListener( 'dragleave', dragLeave, true );
}
function drop( e ) {
  // do the actual work
  dragLeave( e );
}
```

Here's a list of calls:

```
begin drag dragstart
drag enter:  this=e9 - e.target=IMG
drag enter:  this=e9 - e.target=TD
drag enter:  this=e8 - e.target=TD
drag enter:  this=e8 - adding listeners
drag enter:  this=e8 - e.target=IMG
drag leave: this=e8
clearing listeners: this=e8
```

If the "clearing listeners" were not performed, the next step would have been:

```
drop: this=e8
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#div1 {width:350px;height:70px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
</style>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Drag  it</p>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's rarely a reason to manage your event listeners in this way.

If you bind to drop, dragover, dragleave at the same time as you bind to dragenter do you still see the problem?

The HTML dnd api is a little bit weird when [you first look at it](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/09/the_html5_drag.html). Depending on what you are trying to do something simple like

```
onDragOver=function(e) { e.stopPropagation() }
onDrop=function(e) { /* handle drop */ }
```

may be all the listeners you need.

Comment: ended up creating the dragEnter, dragOver, dragLeave and drop listeners with the drag listener and deleting them with the dragEnd.  this works well.  before was having dragEnter create the dragOver, dragLeave and drop listeners, but this did not work because of multiple calls on dragEnter resulting in multiple dragLeave and drop which where not at all synchronized.  aesthetically this was pleasing, but because of lack of synchronism did not work.